# Install Bundler gem with rbenv when provisioning (Chef + Vagrant)

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, bundler, rbenv

I'm using Vagrant + Chef to provision an Ubuntu16.04 vm for rails development. I would like to install Bundler with Chef (using rbenv) but for some reason it fails with the following message: "undefined method `clear_sources' for Custom resource rbenv_gem from cookbook rbenv".

Any ideas?

Thanks!

The content of my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]

chef.add_recipe "apt"
chef.add_recipe "ruby_build"
chef.add_recipe "rbenv::user"
chef.add_recipe "rbenv::vagrant"

chef.json = {
  rbenv: {
    user_installs: [{
      user: 'vagrant',
      rubies: ["2.3.1"],
      global: "2.3.1" ,
      gems: {
        "2.3.1" => [
          { name: "bundler" }
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
end
end
```

Cheffile:

```
site "https://supermarket.getchef.com/api/v1"

cookbook 'apt'
cookbook 'build-essential'
cookbook 'ruby_build', '~> 1.0.0'
cookbook 'rbenv', git: 'https://github.com/aminin/chef-rbenv'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [the official chef-rbenv cookbook](https://github.com/chef-rbenv/ruby_rbenv), your issue was probably fixed by [#110](https://github.com/chef-rbenv/ruby_rbenv/issues/110).

BTW. Any particular reason for not using test-kitchen?